# What is the most efficient method of creating a detailed 3d tileset in a 3d game that uses a grid?

Tags: unity, 3d

Well, the most efficient method might be with how minecraft does the terrain by using a single block for a single grid, but one thing I am concerned about is that the method minecraft uses is poorly mixed near the edges where 2 different blocks meet. I would like the blocks to mix together nicely, similiar to how modern 2d games does their tiles.

I had some thoughts.

Perhaps one could adjust the alpha of the texture so that it blends well near the end? So at the edge, between 2 different blocks type, both of the blocks would exit where 1 of the block would be alpha-blended together with the other block based on the priority value of the block.

That's the idea I have currently but I have some doubts about it.

If there's any inquiry about my question feel free to ask.

Edit: Well, even though I use minecraft as an example, it's not a sandbox game, it's just I would like to use a grid style of terrain that some 2D game uses even when it's not sandbox (e.g. Mark of the Ninja) but in a 3D environment instead. An efficient method of doing that is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you say "creating" a tileset, I presume you mean that you want all these tile transitions pre-baked into textures. I'd recommend against that as the number of transitions you need increases quadratically as your number of tile types increases, and isn't worth any extra efficiency usually.

What you want to look into is [Texture Splatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_splatting) and do this all runtime.

I can't think of anything in particular that would give you extra efficiency when it comes to cell types, except the usual voxel optimizations like storing voxels in an octree and [optimizing that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_voxel_octree), [occlusion culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination), [frustum culling](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/), [LOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail), optimal [mesh generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_generation) etc.

On that last one, as the saying goes, premature optimization is the root of all evil, but if you end up having some extra FPS, you could try rendering your cells to look more "detailed" with algorithms like [marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) / [marching diamonds](http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu/func/return_pdf?pub_id=854) (think the 3D Worms games' destructible terrain).

Edit: [Here's](http://0fps.net/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/) a good read on voxel terrain meshing.

Comment: Ah, didn't thought about the texture splatting part. Although actually, perhaps my question was a bit misleading but the game isn't a sandbox game where the terrain is destructible. I know of some 2D games where they use a grid system for the terrain even when it's not destructible ( e.g. Mark of the Ninja ) so I was thinking of something along those lines, but in 3D instead. The reason for this is that level building might be more fluid and easier, or so I think, as well as being cost-effective. But indeed, the LOD, frustrum culling and all should work out well.